# LaTeX installation query

Tags: installing, texlive

I have just installed TeX Live 2011 using the `install-tl` Perl script on my extenal hard drive. What do I have to do next in order to get LaTeX up and running?
EDIT: i am using ubuntu 11.10. Terribly sorry if the earlier version was vague, i thought mentioning the install-tl script would be specific enough. I type `latex file.tex` into the commandline, and it does not work.

Comment: As it stands this is a pretty vague question. For example, which operating system do you use? Did you try the 'standard' instructions for your OS, and if so what did not work?

Comment: Please read [the installation instructions for Linux](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

Comment: You need to add the path to the TeX Live binaries to your PATH, as mentioned in the message printed at the end of the installation. (By the way, your edit is still terribly vague: what do you mean "does not work"? Please give us the actual error message if any, or explain what happens.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which scheme you installed with TeX Live. You need at least the "basic" scheme to be able to typeset with `latex`. If you haven't specified anything during the installation, TeX Live by default resorts to its "full" scheme, which enables you to explore the full of TeX / LaTeX / ConTeXt / ... as the name suggests.

If you selected the "minimal" scheme or any scheme that doesn't include LaTeX, you can easily correct this with the following command:

```
tlmgr install scheme-basic
```

Next, check if you can compile the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
 Hello world!
 \[ e=mc^2 \]
\end{document}
```

Save it to a file called `test.tex`, open a prompt and type: `latex test.tex`.

If you get an error, check the `.log` file for what LaTeX reports as missing and use `tlmgr` to install the missing parts. You can search the TeX Live repository with `tlmgr search --global <searchterm>`.

One final note: given you mentioned installing on an external hard drive, you should have run the TeX Live installation with the `-portable` option (either through `./install-tl -portable` or by using the GUI and selecting the option). You might finally also need to add the TeX Live bin path to your `PATH`. How to do this depends on your platform -- on unix-based system, you will usually need to edit `/etc/profile` (system-wide configuration) or `$HOME/.bash_profile` (user-wide) and add the following lines

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/texlive/dir./bin
export PATH
```

Happy LaTeXing!

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for the path for the executable, as it were.

Comment: @Debanjan Inside the directory where you installed Tex Live, it's usually either `bin/` or something like `bin/<arch>/`, e.g. `bin/x86_64-linux`.

Comment: after setting the path and exporting it i get the following -<br/>

     `bash: /media/Eru Ilúvatar/texlive2011/bin/i386-linux/latex: Permission denied`

Now why is that? @xavier

Comment: @Debanjan The executable is there, but your users doesn't have the required permissions to run it. Make sure the hard drive was mounted by the user trying to run `latex`. If you are using a file system that supports permissions, make sure the user can read the Tex Live installation directory and has execution rights on the `bin/<arch>` folder contents. Either through cli if you know how to do this, or by typing `sudo nautilus /media/Eru Ilúvatar/`, right-clicking on `texlive2011` and checking the permissions (read+execute for everyone).